# ExtJS 6 GPL vs Commercial what are the real differences?

Tags: javascript, extjs

sorry if this question is stupid, but i need to know:

What is the exact functional difference between ExtJS GPL and Commercial? Taking apart the licensing differences, is there any difference related to widgets, components or functionalities?

(I have been reading Sencha documentation, but i couldn't find anything about it).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As of ExtJs 7, there is an important difference between GPL and Community. The community version is limited to the `modern` framework. `classic` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

No functional differences, except [Pivot Grids](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#pivot-grids) are missing, which are available only for the most expensive tier, see [here](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/newpkg/).

Some other related products that are missing are listed [here](https://www.sencha.com/legal/), but they are not essential in my opinion.

The worst difference is that minor version releases are not available for GPL license, which is mentioned [here](https://www.sencha.com/legal/GPL/). It is an odd, and very likely  intended, decision because all those minor releases usually contain are much needed bug fixes, which you won't have access to for months and sometimes years. Luckily the minor release sources are still available when browsing the Docs site, so you can peak at the fixes and do it yourself. There are tons of minor annoyances and bugs in the core classes that are not getting fixed anytime soon still, so you will be digging through the sources and patching them often in any case, luckily they made it as easy as possible.